# Please how can I update the cache from the code rather than using dev tools

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps, offline

Please, what can I do to make my cache purge and update itself to the new files? Can it be done from my code rather than deleting the existing cache using dev tools

Comment: There is nothing built into JavaScript tp clear the cache. You can do cache busting things, but it is not the same as clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a method along the way using the service workers implementation when activated

```
  self.addEventListener('activate', async event => {
  const keys = await caches.keys();
  keys.map(key =>key!=[the name of your current cache]? caches.delete(key):'');
})
```

then make to add self.skipWaiting() in the install event code so that the use of the new cache can begin as soon as possible